# How to Invoke cognito sign in page when trying to access resource in api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to set up AWS API gateway in our env. I have created an api gateway with a resource and a cognito user pool for authentication. I created an app client in cognito and able to add users. But I am not clear on invoking the sign in page when accessing the endpoint using api gateway. Right now i am passing the JWT token in the Authorization header manually for testing purpose but in realtime, when I hit the api gateway endpoint i want to redirect to the signup/sign-in page programmatically add the auth header once the user authenticated.

Could you please help me understand what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

An API is a backend service usually called through front end app or other backend service.  An API should not assume the caller is a human using a front end, and should not assume the front end is a web app, it might be a mobile application, a watch app, a TV app etc ...

That being said, your API should not redirect to the user authentication page.

The normal workflow would be

1. Customers connect to you web page
2. Code on web page checks if the user is authenticated
3. When user is not authenticated, web page redirects to authentication system.
4. After authentication, authentication system redirects back to your web page
5. Web page collects token generated by authentication system
6. Web page call API, including token in header / query strings.

You can substitute web app here by mobile app or other type of front end.

Check an example here.  https://github.com/dabit3/stockholm-loft-react-native

This is a React App, using Amplify it demonstrates how the app itself is managing the redirection to the authentication page and how it pass authentication token to the API.  The example is using GraphQL API, but you can do something similar with REST API.